# File creation in c#

Tags: c#

I am working on small address book app, I have to make a folder and inside that folder an .xml file, and the problem is that the app creates a folder but it can't create the file!

Here is the code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = 
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    if(!Directory.Exists(path + "\\Address Book - Neca"))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "\\ Address Book - Neca");
    if (!File.Exists(path + "\\Address Book - Neca//settings.xml"))
        File.Create(path + "\\Address Book - Neca//settings.xml");
}
```

Comment: Hint for the future: Use `Path.Combine` instead of `+`ing together strings.

Comment: Check the permission on that Directory where you try to create file. Regards,

Comment: You don't need the `Directory.Exists` check, you can just always call `Directory.CreateDirectory` and if the directory exists it just does nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've improved your code, take a look. Your folder path has spaces between the `\`.

include:

```
using System.IO;
```

And after:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // prepare the path
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        // prepare the folder path
    string folderPath = Path.Combine(path, "Address Book - Neca");
        // prepare the file path
    string settingFilePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "settings.xml");

    if(!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

    if (!File.Exists(settingFilePath))
        File.Create(settingFilePath);

}
```

Comment: @Felipe Oriani Thanks man I've used your code and it works. :D
Also thanks to all of you.

Comment: Nice @Nemanja, remember to check a post as an anwser to help other users with a similar problem and improve stack overflow :)

Comment: Sorry I am new here, how can i do that?

Comment: There is a check above each anwser, choose one :) like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Answer (score 4):

[`File.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx) creates and returns a file stream. The file with its data will only be written when you *close* that file stream.

A convenient way of doing this is by using a `using` block:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(...)) {
    // write to file here
}
```

Also, note that it is not a good idea to first check for the file's existence and then create the file. The file may have been absent during your call to `File.Exists`, then a file of the same name could have been created by some other process, and then your call to `File.Create` would be executed and fail. When attempting to create a file, just try it and catch exceptions to learn that it is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

Your createdirectory method parameter has a space in it before Address

Comment: Using `Path.Combine(path,"Address Book - Neca")` is a good way to make sure mistakes like this do not happen. If you are using .NET 4 or newer you can do `Path.Combine(path,"Address Book - Neca","settings.xml")` for the file too, if not you just need to nest the calls.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the BackSlashes:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = 
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    if(!Directory.Exists(path + "\\Address Book - Neca"))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "\\Address Book - Neca");
    if (!File.Exists(path + "\\Address Book - Neca\\settings.xml"))
        File.Create(path + "\\Address Book - Neca\\settings.xml");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string fileName = path + "\\Address Book - Neca")) 
                if (!File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName, 1024))
                    {
                        Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(e.Message);
                        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
                    }
                }
```